# Azure EventHub Event Format

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

All,

I set up an **EventHub** Namespace and EventHub and was able to successfully send and receive events to it using Python scripts. I was also able to enable the Capture feature and store the events in Azure Blob Storage in Avro format.

I wanted to know more about EventHubs and would be great if someone points me in the right direction:

*[1] During Capture, can the file format be changed to say for example csv or json format so that the files get created in csv/json format? Or is Avro the only one supported?*

*[2] When the Event is in EventHub itself before it gets aged out what is the format of the event - is it json?*

*[3] When the Event data is stored in Azure Blob Storage (in avro format) how do I know what is the structure of the data so that I can create an appropriate schema which I can then use in Azure Data Explorer definition to load data into Kutso database.*

Thanks,

rgn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your questions;

1) Event Hubs Capture writes only in AVRO format today.

2) Service doesn't know about the payload format it is processing and it stores the events in binary format.

3) AVRO format specifies the schema at the top of the file content if this is what you are asking for. You may check here regarding the format details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#exploring-the-captured-files-and-working-with-avro

Comment: I can look at the Avro format only after the avro file is created. However, how would I know the schema in advance so that I can create the Azure Data Explorer infrastructure while deploying EventHub itself? Or is there a way I can extract while the event data is in binary format in EventHub Itself?

Comment: Avro files are written in an intermittent schedule depending on the capture configuration of the subject event hub. By default, files are created either every 5 minutes or whenever buffer reaches 100 MB, basically whichever comes first. Both interval and buffer size settings are configurable. Raw data isn't publicly accessible. I strongly recommend you to look at Event Grid where you can configure triggers for capture events. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/store-captured-data-data-warehouse